# Rate of Convergence of Generalized Iterative Method

Tags: polynomials, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, roots, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the generalized iterative method for finding polynomial roots:

$z_{k+1}=z_k +d\frac{(1/p)^{(d-1)}(z_k)}{(1/p)^{(d)}(z_k)}$

where d is a positive integer. Note that Newton's Method is a particular case of this iterative method , indeed substitute for d=1 directly the result appear, moreover for d=2, the obtained iterative method is the Halley's method .

I try to find the rate of convergence of this iterative method near a simple root. 
I try by induction as we know its quadratic for Newton's method , but i fail to get a  result.
Is there any suggestions , any idea would be  very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

See [Householder methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder%27s_method) on wikipedia. And especially the linked article of Xavier Gourdon [(readable Postscript version)](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/newton.ps).

$d=2$ is the cubically convergent Halley's method, the higher order methods have no individual name.

The order of convergence is $d+1$. However, it requires also $d+1$ Horner evaluations of the function and its derivatives. So with $2(d+1)$ Horner evaluations you can perform $d+1$ Newton steps reducing the error from $ε$ to $ε^{2^{d+1}}$, whereas two steps of the $d$'th Householder method reduce the error to $ε^{(d+1)^2}$. Now $2^{d+1}\ge(d+1)^2$ for $d\ge 3$, that's why you don't see many implementations of them.